# Google Pie Chart generates blank chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I'm using the following json to generate my PieChart, but it generates a blank chart with no error.

The following block is my code to generate the chart:

```
$.post('/admin/relatorios/getVendasCidadeChart', {
        dt_inicio: $("#datepicker-from").val(),
        dt_fim: $("#datepicker-to").val()
    }).done(function(donutData){
        var dados = new google.visualization.DataTable(donutData);
        var options = {
            title: "Vendas por Cidade",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('vendas-cidade'));
        chart.draw(dados, options);
    });
```

The json output by the post request:

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Loja","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Valor(R$)","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Loja Shopping"},{"v":"8620.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Loja Centro"},{"v":"10240.00"}]}]}
```

Chart generated:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfhe4.png

**Update 1**

Fiddle reproducing the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/thatmesg/1/

Comment: Did you check console?

Comment: Yes, no errors thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my values... The column "Valor" is defined as number, but the values was coming as strings with **quotes**...

Just removed the quotes from my JSON and it worked

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Loja","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Valor(R$)","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Loja Shopping","f":null},{"v":8620.00,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Loja Centro","f":null},{"v":10240.00,"f":null}]}]}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thatmesg/3/)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar "issue" but that wasn't an issue. All my pie slices were just returning 0 which may happen and it's logically correct.

Add `sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0` to your `options` variable. It should display the legend even if there will be no data. If you'll see the legend then we can assume that Google Chart library works as expected. If not... then we'll investigate further.

```
var options = {
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 6 },
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0
};
```

EDIT:

I see that you're using wrong type of brackets:

That's how your JSON should look like. If you generate it using PHP, don't forget to use `json_encode`.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Category","Hours"],["Compliance \/ Policy ($0.00)",0],["Harrassment ($0.00)",0],["Productivity ($0.00)",0],["Skills Gap ($0.00)",0],["Values Behaviour ($0.00)",0]]);
```

Also I see that yous JSON contains "keys". You should do something like (remove keys and pass just values to the JSON):

`$final['json'] = json_encode(array_values($pie_hours));`

Comment: Same as before.

I created a fiddle with the problem. I think something is wrong with my json.
Check the fiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/thatmesg/1/

Comment: I'm generating using PHP, and json_encode is used. Which bracket are you talking about ? I've used [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) 
and it says that my JSON is valid

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by "wrong type of brackets"

Comment: Your `dados` variable contains curly brackets and that's wrong. Always start solving your problem by looking into official source: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart. Take a look at some examples there. Data (datos) variable should be built using just square brackets and also the structure of the JSON must match. Fulfill all conditions first and then we can investigate. :)

Comment: But from your source, the DataTable is being generated by an javascript array. 

I want to receive the data from my server, and to do that I need to send it via JSON. See this google chart [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

Comment: Found out... The issue was with my values... The column "Valor" is defined as number, but the values was coming as strings with quotes... Just removed the quotes from my JSON and it worked..

Thank you @slick for your suppport !

I'll answer my question right now...

Comment: Yep. Numeric values should be casted to ints or floats.